# Error 500 using AJAX in select Laravel 5.8

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to get the amount of a specific value from the `select` in my blade. I get `Internal 500` error, I can't locate where it goes wrong. Help is highly appreciated!

**Route**

```
Route::get('/ajax-amount',function(){
     $id = Input::get('id');
     $amount = RoomType::where('id', $id)->get();

     return Response::json($amount);
});
```

**JS**

```
$("#description").change(function(){
     var id = $("#description").val();
     $.get('/ajax-amount?id=' + id,function(data){
    console.log(data);
     });
});
```

**Blade**

```
<select name="description" id="description" class="form-control">
       <option value="">— Select Room Description —</option>
       @foreach ($types as $type)
           <option value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->type}}</option>
       @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: what's the error shown in console?

Comment: using Chrome, in its console (developer tool), you have a tab called 'network'.. when you change the select you will see a red request, and there will be the error description... or just go to "www.yoursite.com/ajax-amount?id=1" and check what's the error

Comment: Thank you for giving me a hint on debugging! I always check only in console, it returned me the error of `Internal 500 server error` so I had no idea what it is. Thank you!

Comment: your welcome, just note that in the network tab, if you click the failed request, you have a smaller tab called 'preview' to check the response text, and so you will see the same as opening on a new tab

Comment: Will keep this in mind, thank you!

Comment: no problem, good luck!